# Shredding XML into SQL Server 2008 table

Tags: sql-server, xml

I am having difficulty in figuring out how to split up an XML string into columns in a database. I have a XML string shown below. And I would love to know the most efficient way to do this using SQL Server 2008.

```
<DATA>
   <Message Action="UPDATE" MessageDate="2015-06-27T19:91:00" Type="TXT" ControlID="Q385906345T373566011"/>
   <Facility FacilityCode="ORBIT" FacilityDescription="Sending Facility"/>
   <SourceSystem HISCode="MILLENNIUM" Description="TKNOWN3"/>
   <EVN Event="P03" Recorded="2015-06-27T00:00:00"/>
   <EMPLOYEE>
      <Employee BirthDate="2014-08-09T00:00:00" Gender="F" MarkedForDelete="0" LastName="CASTILLO" FirstName="TIMA"  Type="MILLE_1367289"/>
   </EMPLOYEE>
   <SUB1>
   <Encounter MarkedForDelete="0" A03Received="0">
      <Location CARE="SUR-R6"/>
   </Encounter>
   </PV1>
   <FT1 SetID="1" TransactionID="2250382928" Date="2015-06-27T00:00:00" Type="CG" Code="74020" Description="DX V" Quantity="1" DepartmentCode="RAA">
      <ProcedureCodeModifier ModifierID="16"/>
      <PerfBy PerfByCode="17300" PerfByFamilyName="Chap" PerfByGivenName="Teresa"/>
      <OrdBy OrdCode="32289" OrdLastName="Hofman" OrdFirstName="Sarah"/>
   </FT1>
</DATA>
```

Thank you in advance

Here is the data I am getting and I am trying to figure a way to parse it into columns such as `FacilityCode`, `EmployeeLastName`, `DepartmentCode`,... etc.

Comment: Can you add the expected table format result

Comment: Action Type Event TransactionID
UPDATE TXT P03 2250382928

Answer (score 1):

Look into SQL Server [`value()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178030.aspx)method  for XML data type and learn a bit of XQuery/XPath expression. This is a working example for demo :

```
declare @xml XML = '<DATA>
   <Message Action="UPDATE" MessageDate="2015-06-27T19:91:00" Type="TXT" ControlID="Q385906345T373566011"/>
   <Facility FacilityCode="ORBIT" FacilityDescription="Sending Facility"/>
   <SourceSystem HISCode="MILLENNIUM" Description="TKNOWN3"/>
   <EVN Event="P03" Recorded="2015-06-27T00:00:00"/>
   <EMPLOYEE>
      <Employee BirthDate="2014-08-09T00:00:00" Gender="F" MarkedForDelete="0" LastName="CASTILLO" FirstName="TIMA"  Type="MILLE_1367289"/>
   </EMPLOYEE>
   <PV1>
   <Encounter MarkedForDelete="0" A03Received="0">
      <Location CARE="SUR-R6"/>
   </Encounter>
   </PV1>
   <FT1 SetID="1" TransactionID="2250382928" Date="2015-06-27T00:00:00" Type="CG" Code="74020" Description="DX V" Quantity="1" DepartmentCode="RAA">
      <ProcedureCodeModifier ModifierID="16"/>
      <PerfBy PerfByCode="17300" PerfByFamilyName="Chap" PerfByGivenName="Teresa"/>
      <OrdBy OrdCode="32289" OrdLastName="Hofman" OrdFirstName="Sarah"/>
   </FT1>
</DATA>'

SELECT 
  @xml.value('(/DATA/Message/@Action)[1]', 'varchar(100)') as Action
  , @xml.value('(/DATA/Message/@Type)[1]', 'varchar(100)') as Type
  , @xml.value('(/DATA/EVN/@Event)[1]', 'varchar(100)') as Event
  , @xml.value('(/DATA/FT1/@TransactionID)[1]', 'varchar(100)') as TransactionID
```

**<kbd>[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7/918)</kbd>**

**output :**

```
| Action | Type | Event | TransactionID |
|--------|------|-------|---------------|
| UPDATE |  TXT |   P03 |    2250382928 |
```

Comment: That is perfect... This answers my question.  Any recommendations on xquery/path material?